# Facebook Like Button in Email in 1-click

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, email

I've been looking around without success. Is it currently possible to implement a Facebook like button in an email and have someone like the content in just 1 click?

Thank you

Paul

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/search?q=like+button+email

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook like button works in 1 of 2 ways:

1. an Iframe in which Facebook shows the correct code (most commonly used)
2. via the Facebook SDK, which requires javascript

Both of the above methods are not available in an email, so my answer would be: No, its not possible.